# TrueCrypt decryption of a not completely encrypted volume

Tags: truecrypt

I'm having trouble encrypting my hard drive with TrueCrypt. The program can not read some sectors of the disk and suggests replacing them with zeros, actually erasing the data. How can I reverse this process and decrypt the disk?

Comment: You can try using ddrescue to take an image of the ciphered disk. then write that image to new media (without bad sectors) and then mount the disk in Truecrypt to see what the remaining damage is. you have to understand, bad sectors are a hardware problem, so Truecrypt really isn't involved much in this issue at all.